# laravel routes with parameters not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

Route with parameters not working and it's throws and error

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException;
```

routes.php

```
Route::any('/share-to-group/(:any)/(:any)',array('as' => 'share-to-group',  
                                 'uses' => 'HomeController@shareToGroup'));
```

within view

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('share-to-group',[ $group['group_id'], $UnixDateTime ]) }}">Something</a>
```

and controller

```
function shareToGroup($group_id,$unixtime){
        echo $group_id.$unixtime;exit;
}
```

what's wrong i am doing?

I have review following link but that's completely different and there is nothing unique between this and i think this is not duplicate.
[How to pass query string params to routes in Laravel4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321274/how-to-pass-query-string-params-to-routes-in-laravel4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass query string params to routes in Laravel4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321274/how-to-pass-query-string-params-to-routes-in-laravel4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Routing with parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters) the correct way to define route with parameters is:

**Basic Route Parameter**

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
{
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

Note: Route parameters cannot contain the - character. Use an underscore (_) instead.

**Optional Route Parameters**

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function($name = null)
{
    return $name;
});
```

Optional Route Parameters With Default Value

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function($name = 'John')
{
    return $name;
});
```

You mistake is that for parameters you use `(:any)` instead of `{any?}`

Your declaration should look like this:

```
 Route::any('/share-to-group/{param1?}/{param2?}',array(
    'as' => 'share-to-group',  
    'uses' => 'HomeController@shareToGroup'
));
```

Comment: agree but I want to access route params in my action and not return from routes.

Comment: @kamlesh.bar The examples show you how to define routes, you can put whatever you want as callback. Look at the end of my post for example with your code.

Comment: thanks that did the trick. i don't why i am unable to accept answer. you should put this at top